# GUI of Stack using Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am making a GUI of Stack using Java. Here is my code

```
     private void StackActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {

      b1=new JButton("Push");
      b2=new JButton("Pop");
      b3=new JButton("Peek");
      b4=new JButton("Clear");
      b1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            pushButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
      });
      tb.add(b1);
      tb.add(b2);
      tb.add(b3);
      tb.add(b4);
      frame_st.add(tb);
      frame_st.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

  }
```

Here I am adding buttons to my toolBar (tb) everything is working fine . I am not getting any error. But after compiling am not getting the desired result . toolBar(tb) is not able to add the buttons (b1,b2,etc)

Comment: how is `tb` initialized?

Comment: private javax.swing.JToolBar tb;

Comment: that's not the initialization, that's the declaration.

Comment: Usually you dont directly add buttons to JToolBar. Recommended ways is to use JToolBar.add(Action a) to add actions

Comment: Do you get any exceptions at runtime?

Comment: And you're not ignoring exceptions -- no empty catch blocks, right?

Comment: I am not ignoring any exceptions..

Comment: If you're adding or removing components from a container after the GUI has been displayed, you must be sure to call `revalidate()` on the container (if it is a JComponent) and then often you must call `repaint()` as well. Also, there's much you're not telling us, including what layout manager tb is using, whether tb is displaying on the JFrame at all, ...  The better quality information that you can tell us, usually the better quality answer we can give you.

Comment: where do i have to call these functions?

Comment: You would call them after you've added/removed components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're adding components after a GUI has been rendered, don't forget to revalidate and repaint containers after you've changed the components they hold.

```
private void StackActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{
   b1=new JButton("Push");
   b2=new JButton("Pop");
   b3=new JButton("Peek");
   b4=new JButton("Clear");
   b1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
         pushButtonActionPerformed(evt);
      }
   });
   tb.add(b1);
   tb.add(b2);
   tb.add(b3);
   tb.add(b4);    
   frame_st.add(tb);
   frame_st.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
   JPanel contentPane = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
   contentPane.revalidate();
   contentPane.repaint();
}
```

Also key here are what layout managers are your tb JPanel and JFrame contentPane using?

Comment: I am having one more problem . I want my toolBar to get resized when my window's maximise button in pressed

Comment: @rick: presumably your JFrame's contentPane is using BorderLayout, and so you would simply add your toolbar to the contentPane at the BorderLayout.NORTH position also known as the BorderLayout.PAGE_START positino.